# AMP Project: Develop safeframe solution

Tags: javascript, ads, amp-html

In #amp-html project I'm going to add a possibility to my adserver to deliver ads inside a safeframe. Is there any "ready-to-use" solution in this project? I can see some "safeframe" strings in the "amp-a4a.js" extension file but I don't really know how to use that. Any info would be welcomed.

Thanks!